# share button taking wrong url

Tags: facebook, url, share

The share button on

http://www.wrappz.com/createyourown/devices

- when clicked - it shows http://usa.wrappz.com and content from http://usa.wrappz.com as well.

I have checked the url with facebook debug tool but the same result. Even if the page is changed and there is no usa.wrappz.com in whole page source ( removing the dropdown on that page - which is the only place it has word usa.wrappz.com ) - it still shows  the contents from usa.wrappz.com.

can anyone help me with this, as it seems facebook share button is not working as it should be.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facebook share button (or the share url) is deprecated, you can read it in the docs:

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

(reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/)

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

(reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

You can maybe find what's wrong here, but the right thing to do is to stop using it altogether.